# how do i return 2 values using pointer? (see the following code)

Tags: c, pointers

```
float roots(float *p,float *r,int j);
main()
{
    float a[3],i;
    float root;
    printf("enter three value");
    scanf("%f%f%f",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2]);
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        roots(&a,&root,i);
    printf("%f\n",root);
    }
}
float roots (float *p,float *r,int j)
{
    if(j==0)
    {
        *r=(- *(p+1)+sqrt((*(p+1) * *(p+1))-4*(*p) * *(p+2)))/2*(*p);
    return(*r);
    }
    if(j==1)
    {
         *r=(- *(p+1)-sqrt((*(p+1) * *(p+1))-4*(*p) * *(p+2)))/2*(*p);
    return(*r);
    }

}
```

In the following program I have calculated the roots of the equation by passing two pointers in function `roots()` and one int value, 
but how can I return those two roots by passing only two pointers and not passing int in the function `roots()`?

Do not use struct to solve the roots of the quadratic equation.

I have use one pointer variable in the function to pass the coefficient of the equation and other to return roots.

Comment: If I'm right the function should be of return type `void`. Within the function you can just assign values to the pointer-variables `p` and `r`. After the function has been called you can use the variables that you passed in to the function as pointers (`a` and `root`).

Comment: `float root[2];`.. `roots(a, root);`

Comment: Please change your loop head to `for(i=0;i<=2;i++)` to pass all three entered values to the function. (1) What is the intention to have different calculations for first and second value? (2) why don't you handle the 3rd value at all? (3) Why does your function return a value, when it is never used?

Comment: Actually is this a proper way to solve a quadratic equation , I think the logic of the program is also faulty..

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the "value", "pointer" and "array" concepts in your code:

In this line

```
    roots(&a,&root,i);
```

Since you want to access its elements there's no need to use the address of (&) operator to pass the array a, since "a" is already a label to the first element of array a, i.e. a already holds the *address* of the first element of the array. Using &a you're actually passing a [reference to the whole array](http://c-faq.com/%7Escs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr#aryvsadr):

> In Standard C, &arr yields a pointer, of type pointer-to-array-of-T, to the entire array.
>
> For a simple array
>
> int a[10];
>
> a reference to a has type `pointer to int,'' and &a is` pointer to array of 10 ints.''

In the definition of the function

```
float roots (float *p,float *r,int j)
```

you mix the dereference operator and the multiplication operator, and this makes the code a lot less readable and more bug prone:

```
    *r=(- *(p+1)+sqrt((*(p+1) * *(p+1))-4*(*p) * *(p+2)))/2*(*p);
```

It seems like you're trying to implement the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation), but this is not immediately obvious.

Finally, in the definition of the function you are also returning a copy of r value using the dereference operator, but the result is discarded by main and the function operates on pointers: there's no need for a return statement, you can change the return data type to void and remove.

```
return(*r);
```

from the code, since any operation on a value accessed through dereferencing a pointer is equivalent to directly accessing the variable actually holding the value, i.e. since you passed &root as an argument, any operation involving *r already updates the value in the root var.

Answer (score 0):

To return two values from the function, declare the function with pointers to the two values, e.g.

```
void roots( float *p, float *root1, float *root2 )
{
    *root1 = ...
    *root2 = ...
}
```

and then call the function with the addresses of the two values, e.g.

```
int main( void )
{
    float a[3], r1, r2;

    // ... get user input for a[]

    roots( a, &r1, &r2 );
    printf( "%f %f\n", r1, r2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192926/how-do-i-return-2-values-using-pointer-see-the-following-code#comment46599807_29192926), you can use an array:

```
void roots(float *p, float *r);

int main()
{
    float the_roots[2];
    ...
    roots(a, the_roots);
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", the_roots[i]);
    }
}

void roots (float *p,float *r)
{
    // I copied the below code "as is"; bugs may be concealed within
    r[0]=(- *(p+1)+sqrt((*(p+1) * *(p+1))-4*(*p) * *(p+2)))/2*(*p);
    r[1]=(- *(p+1)-sqrt((*(p+1) * *(p+1))-4*(*p) * *(p+2)))/2*(*p);
}
```

The function receives a pointer to the first element of an array of 2, not just a pointer to a variable. To describe this, change your function's prototype to this:

```
void roots(const float coefficients[3], float the_roots[2]);
```

This is functionally the same, but better describes the parameters.

In addition: what about equations that don't have roots? You might want to check that inside your function, and return the number of roots too, e.g. using the return value of the function.

BTW a standard library function [`div`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/div) returns two values using a `struct`; the question states "Do not use struct to solve the roots of the quadratic equation" without any justification, so maybe `struct` still is an acceptable option.